# Foundation different style for small - medium - large

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I would like to give different CSS to H2 when his parent is large - medium - small.

Here my HTML:

```
            <div class="category-box large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">
                <h2 class="category-name">My title</h2>
                <div class="hide-for-small">Everything you need to know about using the framework.</div>
            </div>
```

I tryed this kind of selection:

```
.category-box.large-6 h2{}
.category-box.medium-6 h2{}
.category-box.small-12 h2{}
```

But is not working as i want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use media-queries to achieve this.
Take a look at [the foundation media-queries docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html) to get the correct settings to use. (Or you could just find them inside the css)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { /* small */
.category-box h2{/*small h2 style here}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { /* medium */
.category-box h2{}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) { /* large */
.category-box h2{}
}
```